# How can I store the y value of a chart series in a label on my page?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am curious how I can access the value of a YValueMember in a chart that I am populating through a database and display that value in a label. Basically I want to set a labels text equal to the y value of my chart.

I am populating my chart through a db query and setting the YValueMembers to the alias I use within my query

```
SELECT ( SELECT SUM(DealerNet) FROM Agreement WHERE VoidDate IS NULL
AND IssueDate BETWEEN @PFOM AND @date) AS Actual,
(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Sales
WHERE [Year] BETWEEN YEAR(@PFOM) AND YEAR(@date)
AND [Month] BETWEEN MONTH(@PFOM) AND MONTH(@date)) AS Projected
```

I then pass this query to a function I have to populate a DataTable called GetData() as seen in the call below.

GetData() Function:

```
Private Shared Function GetData(cmdSQL As SqlCommand, ByVal Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable
    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WarrantyConnectionString").ToString
    End If

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

Chart Code:

```
Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(query)
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = previousMonthDateToday
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@PFOM", SqlDbType.Date).Value = previousFirstOfMonth
            pmtdChart.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
            pmtdChart.Series(1).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
            pmtdChart.Legends(0).Enabled = True
            pmtdChart.Series(0).XValueMember = xMember1
            pmtdChart.Series(1).XValueMember = xMember2
            pmtdChart.Series(0).YValueMembers = "Actual"
            pmtdChart.Series(1).YValueMembers = "Projected"
            lblPMTDprojected.Text = pmtdChart.Series(1).ToString()
            lblPMTDbilled.Text = pmtdChart.Series(0).ToString()
            pmtdChart.DataSource = GetData(cmdSQL)
            pmtdChart.DataBind()
```

The GetData Function takes the query above and populates a DataTable, I don't know if I can pull directly from the Datatable within my function and I'm not terribly sure how I would do that, or If I need to pull the value from the chart that I am using.
I have tried the following in the Chart Code:

```
label.Text = Chart.Series(0).ToString
label.Text = Chart.Series(0).Points(0).ToString()
label.Text = Chart.Series(0).YValueMembers("Actual").ToString
label.Text = Chart.Series(0).YValueMembers(0).ToString
```

The first quite simply pulls the text value I have assigned to

```
pmtdChart.Series(0).YValueMembers = "Actual"
```

The second returns an exception error stating "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

The Third returns an exception stating "Conversion From String "Text" to Type "Integer" is not valid.

And the fourth simply returns the first character of "Actual"

Technically I can simply pull this value from my database and assign it to the label, but I am wondering if there is a way to just snag it from my chart so I don't have to query the db again, considering I am using a similar query to populate the chart in the first place.

Any help or tips regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated and I feel like there should be a way to do what I am trying to do.  If more information is needed I would be happy to supply it.

Comment: Seems you've really got a number of issues here, but I'm not 100% sure you've given the info to even answer any of them, at least the sqlCommand text would help.  General suggestion though that might help solve all of this.  Execute your query to fill a datatable, then you can use that to do what you want in regard to the label AND bind it to your chart without needing to make multiple DB hits

Comment: @Hursey, thanks for the reply and my apologies for not having all the needed information. I have updated my original post.  In the chart code I am passing the query to a function and the function then populates a data table.  I don't know if I can pull from that data table from outside of the GetData function. I would appreciate any help from here.

Comment: If GetData() is returning a data table, then all you need would be something like `dim queryTable as DataTable = GetData(cmdSQL)` then `pmtdChart.DataSource = queryTable`  That makes it available for both potential uses.  Also looking at your SQL, think one of your problems will be you don't have a field called _Actual_ in your resulting query results.

Comment: Hey @Hursey, Thank you for your help,  that allowed me to solve the problem I was having.  If you'd like, feel free to post that solution as an answer as I would love to give you credit for your solution.

Comment: I would, but don't really feel it's an answer to your original question, more just an alternate way to skin the cat so to speak.  By all means post your solution and mark it as an answer though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem I was having above by creating a second data table outside of the GetData() function and then using the GetData() function to populate the second data table. This allowed me to access the specific row/column that held the value I needed

```
actual = dt.Rows(0)("Actual").ToString()
            projected = dt.Rows(0)("Projected").ToString()
```

I was then able to use these specific values where I needed them outside of the GetData() function.